# Sorting and printing a file in bash UNIX

Tags: bash, sorting, scripting

I have a file with a bunch of paths that look like so:

```
7 /usr/file1564
7 /usr/file2212
6 /usr/file3542
```

I am trying to use `sort` to pull out and print the path(s) with the most occurrences.  Here it what I have so far:

```
cat temp| sort | uniq -c | sort -rk1 > temp
```

I am unsure how to only print the highest occurrences. I also want my output to be printed like this:

```
7 1564
7 2212
```

7 being the total number of occurrences and the other numbers being the file numbers at the end of the name.  I am rather new to bash scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Haven't you asked at least two other questions related to this problem already?

Comment: ... what is your criteria for `highest occurrences`?

Comment: This is my second question about this specific issue but I decided to delete it and make a new one because it was poorly worded and had no answers.

Comment: @ptierno the highest number in the first column (7 in this case)

Comment: Delete-and-replace will eventually get you banned if you do it too much (especially as a new user without a whole lot of positive track record). Edit questions to make them better, rather than replacing them.

Comment: Thank you. I will make sure to do that from now on.

Comment: BTW, you can't use the same `temp` file as both the start and the end of your pipeline: The destination file gets cleared *when the pipeline is first set up*, before the program run at the beginning of the pipeline is started.

Answer (score 2):

To emit only the first line of output (with the highest number, since you're doing a reverse numeric sort immediately prior), pipe through `head -n1`.

To remove all content which is not either a number or whitespace, pipe through `tr -cd '0-9[:space:]'`.

---

To filter for only the values with the highest number, allowing there to be more than one:

```
{
  read firstnum name && printf '%s\t%s\n' "$firstnum" "$name" 
  while read -r num name; do
    [[ $num = $firstnum ]] || break
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$num" "$name"
  done
} < temp
```

Comment: There could possibly be more than one highest number.  How could I handle that?

Comment: thats where the criteria i asked you about comes in.

Comment: In that case you'd either work with awk or a `while read` loop with some logic.

Comment: Very cool use of `tr`! I read the manual just now to learn about `-c` and `-d`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid sort and you are allowed to use awk, then you can do this:

```
awk '{
 if($1>maxcnt) {s=$1" "substr($2,10,4); maxcnt=$1} else
 if($1==maxcnt) {s=s "\n"$1" "substr($2,10,4)}} END{print s}' \
temp
```